# Multidimensional subscripting, why use a proxy over pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Quick question, the only thing I see when I google this topic is people saying that using a Proxy is the way to go. Why is returning a pointer not viable?

Examples!

```
class example{
private:

int** arr;

public:
    int* operator[](const int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }
};
```

We just tried calling

```
 cout << example[0][0]; 
 5
```

and it worked, why should I go through the trouble creating a proxy class and calling the proxys operator[] to reach one more "depth" in the array?

Comment: Well, why do you need a class instead of a `int**` in the first place? `example[0][0]` would work on `int**` as well.

Comment: Usually a proxy is "needed" because the data is not accessible via a pointer to a pointer. But most of the time you don't need `[x][y]` access anyway.

Comment: The class is a Matrix class that can perform matrix multiplication, rotation projection etc etc... I just made this example class just now!

Comment: @PatrikNyman _"The class is a Matrix class ..."_ It would be probably better then, to have a helper class like `MatrixRow`, that provides it's own overload for `operator[]` and return `MatrixRow` with the `Matrix::operator[]` overload.

Comment: I do have that, but my question is, why wouldnt I do it like the example above? It does work and compile just fine!

Comment: As I said, usually you don't have the data in a way that can be accessed with a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a proxy for the second subscript or, as some people suggested in comments,  a `Row` class instead which will be useful for more things than subscripting.

That said, I like the proxy approach because it ressebles the classic bidimensional array or pointer-to-pointer subscript sintaxes. But **are they the best (Readable, simple, efficient) alternative?** I'm not sure.

There is a much simpler alternative: **Overload `operator()` for n-dimensional subscripting**

```
class matrix
{
public:
    int operator()(std::size_t row , std::size_t column ) const
    {
        return _matrix[row][column];
    }
};
```

This is a pretty known technique too, used by many algebra libraries. For fully generic (n-dimensional) libraries I think it fits better than a succession of proxies and `[][][][][]...`. Also using variadic templates its easier to write a true n-dimensional generic subscript operator.

Comment: I agree `operator()` is much easier. Also, consider `operator[]` and a tuple.